# Custom Currency Format in C#

Tags: c#

I have a function:

```
string FormatCurrency(string currencyCode, decimal amount)
```

Example:

```
Input: "USD", 1230.56
Output: "USD 1,230.56"

Input: "USD", 1230.00
Output: "USD 1,230"

Input: "VND", 1200000
Output: "1.200.000 VND"
```

I want to join culture format(with code, not symbols) and custom format ("#,##.##").
How can I implement?
Thanks

My code, I got from Internet:

```
CultureInfo culture = (from c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                       let r = new RegionInfo(c.LCID)
                       where r != null
                       && r.ISOCurrencySymbol.ToUpper() == currencyCode.ToUpper()
                       select c).FirstOrDefault();

if (culture == null)
{
    return amount.ToString("#,##.##");
}

return string.Format(culture, "{0:C2}", amount);
```

but the output is "$1,200.00". My expected result is "USD 1,200"

Comment: Can you please put your code, what you have tried for this..

Comment: I just updated, please check! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hackish, but you can do something like:

```
CultureInfo culture = (from c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
               let r = new RegionInfo(c.LCID)
               where r != null
               && r.ISOCurrencySymbol.ToUpper() == currencyCode.ToUpper()
               select c).FirstOrDefault();
if(culture == null)
{
  // fall back to current culture if none is found
  // you could throw an exception here if that's not supposed to happen
  culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;            
}
culture = (CultureInfo)culture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = currencyCode;

// Add spaces between the figure and the currency code
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern == 0 ? 2 : 3;
var cnp = culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern;
switch(cnp)
{
  case 0: cnp = 14; break;
  case 1: cnp = 9; break;
  case 2: cnp = 12; break;
  case 3: cnp = 11; break;
  case 4: cnp = 15; break;
  case 5: cnp = 8; break;
  case 6: cnp = 13; break;
  case 7: cnp = 10; break;
}
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = cnp;

return amount.ToString("C" + ((amount % 1) == 0?"0":"2"), culture);
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/30f7u3

For:

```
FormatCurrency("USD", 1230.56M);
FormatCurrency("USD", 1230.00M);
FormatCurrency("VND", 1200000M);
```

I get:

```
USD 1,230.56
USD 1,230
1.200.000 VND
```

Comment: You didn't check if no culture have found which will throw an error. And it is not enough for negative pattern to check if it is 0 or 1 , there are 16 cases for negative patterns.

Comment: @Caesar that is right, I added the remark for the problem :-) And yes, a better check case should be done for negative patterns, you are indeed right

Comment: @Caesar there, fixed :-)

Comment: Great job!, I will keep my answer as a base for the solution. but I recommend your solution as a full asnwer.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much! Yesterday I tried this solution: "Get culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator. If it equals "," then currency code before amount. If it equals "." then currency code after amount."

Comment: @Danie `CultureInfo` and `NumberFormatInfo` are deep and it's easy to forget something if you want to construct it yourself. I just preferred using an existing culture and changing only the needed parts to comply with the specifications :-) Glad it works for you

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you. If I understand right you want to show everything as the current cultrue, just you want to change how the currency will be shown.

This is the basics and you can continue on your own.

```
        CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = currencyCode;
        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 2;

        return string.Format(culture, "{0:C2}", amount);
```

The result for me was USD 42,55.

Comment: yours is a bit confusing, remove the decimal separator change, he did not request that, and when writing currencies it's confusing when you are expecting one to see the other. Also need to add how to not print decimals if they are zero

Comment: This works for `USD` and with decimals. For `VND` it will print `VND` before the number, you need to account for that too.

Comment: (also, this will only print decimal separatos according to the current culture, not to the culture specified by the currency code)

Comment: That is true, it will show the currency according to current cultrue.

Answer (score 0):

a bit ugly but somthing like this would probably work unless you decide to use culture and currency format

```
var output = String.Format ("{0} {1:### ### ##0.00}",currencyCode,amount)
```

for currency format using culture use

```
var output = amount.ToString ("C");
```